# gcc 4.6.2 installation with cloog and ppl

Tags: gcc, configure, gcc4

I want to install gcc 4.6.2 with cloog and ppl. I have both the libraries installed in my system. When I try to do `./configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-ppl=/usr/lib --with-cloog=/usr/lib`, I get an error  `Cannot find the directories "/usr/lib/lib" or "/usr/lib/include"` So, I tried `./configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-ppl --with-cloog`. In this case, I get `Unable to find a usable ppl`. Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your system is? You also don't say what you've checked to ensure that you really do have the libraries installed? So, here's one common gotcha that might be your problem.

Assuming you're on Linux, many distro have two packages for each library:

E.g.

- libcoolstuff
- libcoolstuff-dev

You only need the first package to run programs that use it, but you need both to compile those programs.

Comment: Hello, I was able to solve the problem. There was a new error wrt version of the ppl library installed